# for xml path() not working "Incorrect syntax near 'XML'"

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to query in one of our SQL Server database using `for xml path` to concatenate string values and I got this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'XML'

But when I try to use the same query on another SQL Server it works fine...
We're using SQL Server 2008, below is my script:

```
 SELECT
     T1.Field1
     ,  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(T2.Field2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
              FROM 
                Table1 T2
              WHERE
                T2.Field1 = T1.Field1
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' )AS [resultField]
  FROM Table1 T1
```

Comment: Either this is part of a larger query that is broken, or you've completely misidentified the source of the error. If I take your query and substitute table and column names for an actual table I have in my database, it executes without errors

Comment: thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, i have tried to execute it in different server and it work perfectly. let say in server A my script is working but in server B it display an error. both server is using sql 2008.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are the different SQL Servers?

Comment: Are you using lower compatibility level?